# $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k| \leq |\mathbf{x}| \leq \sqrt{n} \cdot |\max(\mathbf{x})|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2,\dots ,x_n)$ and let $\max(\mathbf{x})$ equal the coordinate in $\mathbf{x}$ with the greatest value.

So I am trying to show the following inequality: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k| \leq |\mathbf{x}| \leq  \sqrt{n} \cdot |\max(\mathbf{x})|$$

I was able to show the left inequality by applying the Cauchy-Bunyakovski-Schwarz inequality on the vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $(1,1, \dots,1)$: $$|(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\cdot(1,1,\dots,1)|\leq |(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)| |(1,1,\dots,1)| \\ \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k| \leq \sqrt{n} |\mathbf{x}|$$

When it comes to the right inequality, I am somewhat stuck. Any hint or solution would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
|x|^2 
&= \sum_{i=1} x_i^2 \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1} \max(x)^2 \\
&\leq n \cdot \max(x)^2 \\
|x| &\leq \sqrt{n} |\max(x)|
\end{align}$$